# Steam mobile push notifications not working

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

Since 4 months ago, the steam mobile stop giving me notifications about Verification code, Friend message, etc. If I request Verification code on another pc, steam mobile crashes with no why. Is it for me or common problem?

Edit: 4 months ago, my phone was LG G5, then recently changed to Galaxy S9. Both phone does not work. I did reinstall and relogin several times, but that wasn't a solution for me.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you provide a bit more information? Which phone do you use?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app?

Comment: Edited with more information. I tried reinstall and relogin, but that wasn't a solution for me.

Comment: I've got the same issue but it started only recently within the last couple weeks. Every time I get any kind of Steam notification, the app crashes in the background. Galaxy S7 Edge.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj Yes me too. Even if I request Steam Market confirm, it also crash the app in background.

Comment: With the latest update, this has stopped happening for me.